# Login page in codeigniter error fixing

Tags: codeigniter

user.php(controller)

```
<?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view_login');


    }
    public function login(){
        echo 'You landed Here!!!';
    }
}

?>
```

view_login.php(view)

```
<body>

<h1>Please Login!</h1>
<p>Use the Form below to login to our site...</p>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

    <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'user/login'); ?>

            <label>Username</label>

                <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username'));?>


            <label>Password</label>

                <?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password'));?>


            <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit'), 'Submit'); ?>

<?php   echo form_close();?>
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/user/';
$config['encryption_key'] = 'REALLY_LONG_NUMBER';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

CAn anyone tell what is wrong with this code ? After hitting the submit button the control is not going to user controller function login and it is not displaying the message "you have landed here". I dont if the base url is correct or not and  the default controller should be specified or not.

Comment: Specify the default controller in routes.php and base url as http://localhost/codeigniter/ in config.php

Comment: try creating another controller Verifylogin and in its index function print something. in your view_login.php, change <?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'user/login'); ?> to <?php echo form_open('verifylogin'); ?>. so when you click submit the index function of verifylogin controller should be invoked. also in user and verifylogin controller, specify its constructor. like function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

Comment: replace if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); with defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

Answer (score 2):

If you're removing index.php from your URL, replace your configuration 'base_url' in file config.php become like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

else, replace your configuration 'base_url' in file config.php become like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php';
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my answer makes you misunderstand. Removing index.php from URL mean you make htaccess to remove it. If you running codeigniter by default, you just replace config 'base_url' with my last code (above).

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.php`

```
$route['default_controller'] = "";//you must provide your default controller name
```

and `form` open should be

```
<?php echo form_open('user/login'); ?>
```

In `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';//remove this
```

and you removed `['index_page']`, So you have to place `.htaccess` defiantly

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where should u type htaccess and what is this code <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: if you r not providing the base_url how do you run the code ?

Comment: can index page be provided instead of htaccess ?

Comment: @cd4xltech `.htaccess` should place out side of application folder. and ***no need to declare `base_url`***

Answer (score 0):

Its not still working....
user.php

```
<?php
```

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('view_login');


}
public function login(){
    echo 'You landed Here!!!';
}
```

}

?>

view_login.php

```
body>

<h1>Please Login!</h1>
<p>Use the Form below to login to our site...</p>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

    <?php echo form_open('user/login'); ?>

            <label>Username</label>

                <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username'));?>


            <label>Password</label>

                <?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password'));?>


            <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit'), 'Submit'); ?>

<?php   echo form_close();?>
```

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user";
```

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

$config['base_url'] = '';

htaccess.php

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
```

Deny from all


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I got your point.

If you are using form and base_url(), You have to use helper for that. I have made demo and its working.
This helper is using for redirecting you page through controller. For this you have to make constructor and that constructor is called automatically when the controller called.

user.php:

```
<?php
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');

    }


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('view_login');


    }
    public function login(){
        echo 'You landed Here!!!';
    }
}

?>
```

view_login.php:

```
<body>

<h1>Please Login!</h1>
<p>Use the Form below to login to our site...</p>

<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'user/login'); ?>

            <label>Username</label>

                <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username'));?>


            <label>Password</label>

                <?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password'));?>


            <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'submit'), 'Submit'); ?>

<?php   echo form_close();?>
```